# HTML/CSS Make table full width while having float right image

Tags: html, css, html-table, width, css-float

I would like to make a table full (remaining) width without getting pushed away by an "float: right" image. The (simplified) code is like this:

```
<div>
<img style="float: right;">
<table>
...
</table>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Even more text</p>
...
</div>
```

If give the table the style `"width: 100%"` it is displayed below the image with the full width. If I do not set the width it has the minimum size to fit the text without line breaks. I would like to have it fill out all space left of the image (with a minimum size so it gets pushed away in extreme cases). I couldn't find any solution for this.

Edit: sorry, maybe I wasn't clear what I would like the result to look like, I created an image. The tricky part is the table should extend all over to the image and the text should start directly below the table, even if the image is bigger (that's the part I cannot get working using flex) [image: Example of Website]

Comment: Tables don't flow like text around a float.  If you want things to display side-by-side, you can use flexbox.

Comment: What defines the width of the image. Is it just to use its natural width?

Comment: The width of the image is fixed as absolute value (in pixels). The total width (table+image) is not fixed (depends on screen)

Comment: So you can set the width of the table using  a css calc.

Answer (score 1):

you wanna try this solution, you can change the size of the image all you want

```
<div style="display: flex;">
<img src="img.png" style="float: right; width: 90%">
<table style=" width: 100%; border: 1px solid; ">
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid;">Some text</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid;">Some text</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid;">Some text</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid;">Some text</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid;">Some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid;">Even more text</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid;">Even more text</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid;">Even more text</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid;">Even more text</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid;">Even more text</td>
    </tr>


</table>

<p>Some text</p>
<p>Even more text</p>
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width:100%;">
<div style="max-width:50%; 
float:left;display:block;">
<table border=1 
 cellpadding=60px>
 <tr>
 <th>1</th>
 <th>2</th>
 <th>3</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>3</td>    
 </table>

<p>Some text</p>
<p>Even more text</p>
 ...
</div>
<div style="max-width:50%; float:right;">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ37waf3hj3eVvTy40XYee0lQ6uVGJTx7m3Q&usqp=CAU" 
style="float:right; 
height:auto; 
width:100%; display:block;">
 </div>
 </div>
```